# Is there any way to disable rollback for TokuDB?

Tags: mysql, tokudb

I have Percona MySql v8.0.18-9 installed with TokuDB enabled.

I started a LOAD DATA query where I was loading a 100GB file into a TokuDB table. Based on the initial speed of the load, it seemed like the query would take 24 hours.

After 24 hours, it seemed like the query had slowed down considerably and would take five days. So I killed it, and it looked like the rollback would take two days to complete, so I restarted MySql server (I know. I know. Stupid thing to do).

MySql restarted and is now in the rollback mode

```
Sat May 23 16:30:35 2020 PerconaFT lsn 127036559316 abort xid 1964456650:0 71162880/3245608285 2%
Sat May 23 16:30:50 2020 PerconaFT lsn 127036559316 abort xid 1964456650:0 71511040/3245608285 2%
Sat May 23 16:31:05 2020 PerconaFT lsn 127036559316 abort xid 1964456650:0 71845888/3245608285 2%
```

At this rate it looks like the rollback will take 2 days to complete.

I don't care about the data in this table. So I want to know if there is any way to stop the rollback, so that I don't have to wait for the 2 days to start another Load Data query (this time with hopefully significant improvements to table structure by deleting unnecessary indexes)

I tried searching around but could only find that the file tokudb.rollback is the reason for this. Is there anyway to empty/delete this file without causing any issues?

Innodb seems to have an option to set innodb_force_recovery to 3 which will disable the recovery.  I can't find anything like that for tokudb.